# symfony multilingue in URL

Tags: symfony, routes

I have a multi-language internet site, the problem is that I do not see how constantly put monsite.fr/fr/ and when we choose the English that changes in monsite.fr/en/

I know how a default GET variable but it does not appear constantly ...

If anyone knows how I can manage it best would top!

Thank you !

Comment: Best way for me is always this bundle: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle

Comment: The symfony demo application also shows a blog with multi language support. You can just install it and copy some of the code to your own project. http://symfony.com/blog/introducing-the-symfony-demo-application